# Ebook reader for xml File

Tags: android

I converted an eBook to many xml files, I want to develop an Android application for reading it, how can I do it? and how can I do a quick search in 4000 xml files ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - you need the Activity, to scroll through all the View? I offer the following: http://marcreichelt.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html. This will help you make Activity, that division your xmls on the many pages and flipping through these pages while reading. Each page - your xml.

And if you need to parse all xml, you can read this: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152